Firebase Realtime Database Data Sending Loop
Problem : i am trying to send single recipe object to the firebase to sotre it but when i am trying to do that insted of sending the sprecific recipe only one time it send the same recipe multiple time and let me inform you guys there is no multiple dispacing of this actions and also i don't think it cause of multiple dispaching of actions like a loop
***insted of that i thing it cause of the logic and code i use to send data to the database.for example : this.firebase.list(/..).set.... here i am talking about this line
i actually test the syntex or code for sending data to the firebase and there i see it indeed cause multiple sending insted of single data send and also i didn't use any ngrx while testing to make it more staightfard . [note : we can send data to the firebase in multiple way]
here i am providing the code which responsible for the repeted recipe sending in my angular app [note: code doesn't have any error. it also send data to firebase and in firebase it also store but insted of sending data only one time there is multiple time sending the same data for store]
  addRecipe$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fromRecipeActions.addRecipe),
      switchMap((action) =>
        this.firebaseDatabase
          .list<Recipe>('/recipes')
          .valueChanges()
          .pipe(
            map((recipes) => {
              const keys = recipes.map((recipe: Recipe) => recipe.id);
              const index =
                keys.length > 0 ? Math.max(...keys.map(Number)) + 1 : 0;
              const recipeWithId = { ...action.recipe, id: index.toString() };
              return { recipeWithId, index };
            }),
            switchMap(({ recipeWithId, index }) => {
              const specificRecipeRef = ref(getDatabase(), `/recipes/${index}`);
              return from(
                this.firebaseDatabase
                  .object(`/recipes/${index}`)
                  .set(recipeWithId)
              ).pipe(
                map(() =>
                  fromRecipeActions.addRecipeSuccess({
                    recipe: recipeWithId,
                  })
                ),
                catchError((error) => {
                  console.error('Error adding recipe:', error);
                  return of(
                    fromRecipeActions.recipesOperationFail({
                      error: 'Failed to add recipe! Try again',
                    })
                  );
                })
              );
            }),
            catchError((error) => {
              console.error('Error during addRecipe effect:', error);
              return of(
                fromRecipeActions.recipesOperationFail({
                  error: 'Failed to add recipe! Try again',
                })
              );
            })
          )
      )
    )
  );

